# osm2pgrouting fails with "cannot open"

Tags: osm2pgrouting

I try this code:

```
cd osm2pgrouting
file http://.....com/veriler/andorra.osm conf mapconfig.xml dbname postgres username postgres
```

dbname, username and web address are correct.
But it gives an error.[image: error.]

Answer (score 2):

osm2pgrouting is a converter function that allows you to import osm data into your postgis database. Instead of changing into a directory called 'osm2pgrouting' (like you are doing above), you should be calling 'osm2pgrouting' as an executable like this example:

```
[root@server somedir]# osm2pgrouting -file "data/sampledata.osm" \
                          -conf "/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml" \
                          -dbname routing \
                          -user postgres \
                          -clean
```

You can find more information at this excellent, FOSS4G workshop tutorial here: (see section 4.2) http://workshop.pgrouting.org/0.6.1/en/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html

Comment: Hi @cm1 I'm try this code and return error: https://ibb.co/hfujnQ

Comment: Are you sure you have osm2pgrouting installed correctly?  see this link http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html

Comment: yes, install is correct. But still, I reinstalled, but the same mistake came again

Comment: Make sure your PATH environment variable includes the path to the executable. You can check what your PATH variable contains by doing a [root@server ~]# echo $PATH  It should include entries like /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin  for example.

Comment: [root@server ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
thats way?

Comment: To only query what the PATH variable holds just enter 'echo $PATH' like this: [root@server ~]# echo $PATH

Comment: Latest workshop given just a couple of days ago is this: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.4.11/en/chapters/prepare_data.html#id10

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two issues:

First, you are attempting to change directories into the executable `osm2pgrouting` with cd. You should simply call `osm2pgrouting` with its required parameters.

Second, in previous comments you mentioned attempting to run this without `cd`. It appears that you are missing the flags in your call. Change this:

```bash
osm2pgrouting file http://.....com/veriler/andorra.osm \
              conf mapconfig.xml \
              dbname postgres \
              username postgres
```

... to this:

```bash
osm2pgrouting -file http://.....com/veriler/andorra.osm \
              -conf mapconfig.xml \
              -dbname $DB \
              -username $USER
```

... where `$DB` should be changed to the name of your desired database and `$USER` should be changed to a user with access to the desired database.